# Is Unity Answers associated with Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

http://answers.unity3d.com seems to have a similar format and style to the stack exchange sites, so I was wondering if they were associated in any way.

Comment: No it's not part of Stack Exchange as it does not have its header, where you can log in, see list of sites etc. SE got many clones, some legal and some not.